# How do I count unique visits base on date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count

I have a reports table where i count hits by just using the code below.

```
// Get hits
    $hits_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `reports` WHERE `stuff_id` = ".$row->id."");
    $fetch_hits = mysql_fetch_array($hits_query);
    $hits = $fetch_hits['count'];
```

That code works great and does exactly what i want but what i want now is how to get unique hits?

In my reports table i store every access so theres multiple log for each user base on the `stuff_id` . In my reports table I store the date as 01-23-2013 on each report, along with the user ip and `stuffed` which every 24 hours change from 2 to 1.

Comment: Please look into using `mysqli` or `PDO` commands as `mysql` commands are deprecated and no longer supported. `mysql` commands are vulnerable to sql injection attacks and pose a security risk.

Comment: i just barely know how to code can you help me?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, 
[here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: Thanks ill start learning mysqli or pdo which do you reccomend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a field that uniquely identifies the user. I am going to assume for my example that it is `user_ip`. Change this:

```
$hits_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `reports` WHERE `stuff_id` = ".$row->id."");
```

To this:

```
$hits_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `user_ip`) AS `count` FROM `reports` WHERE `stuff_id` = ".$row->id."");
```

**NOTE:** mysql library will be deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and removed in future versions of PHP. It would be a good idea to start planning a migration away from it.

Comment: Dont you have to incorporate the date from my understanding this will get get distinct base on ip but i consider any hit once in 24 hour period as unique

Comment: All you have to do then is add a group by date. It will show you unique visitors for each 24 hour period. From there you can sum up the total.

Comment: My good friend i dont know how to do that as i store date like 01-23-2013 should i change it?

Comment: Add this to the end of the query `GROUP BY date_column_name`. This will however result in multiple rows. You can wrap it in a subselect or loop through your results and add up the counts.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
$hits_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `user_ip`) AS `count` FROM `reports` WHERE `stuff_id` = ".$row->id."");
```

Or if you want a unique response, you can do this:

```
$user-IP = "Put here the ip adress of the user that you want";
$hits_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `reports` WHERE `user_ip` = ".$user-IP."");
```